# " 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'pack_forget' "

Tags: python, tkinter

When I try to run .pack_forget() on the 'canvas' attribute of the 'start screen' object in the revealregisterscreen() subroutine an error occurs (Image below).

Why does this happen? Please help!

The 'canvas' attribute is defined in the standard class class

The 'button2' attribute is defined in the standard class class (it is the register button that when clicked calls the revealregisterscreen subroutine)

```
class standardclass:
    def __init__(self, labeltext, b1t, b1c, b2t, b2c): #creates the initalization subroutine and passes the parameters in the bracket
        self.canvas = Canvas(root, width=600, height=600, highlightthickness=0,  bg='#A9E2f3').pack()
        self.titlelabel = Label(self.canvas, text=labeltext, font=('Arial', 30), bg='#A9E2f3').place(x=125,y=20) 
        self.button1 = Button(self.canvas, text=b1t, command=b1c, font=('Arial', 30), relief='flat').place(x=100,y=550) 
        self.button2 = Button(self.canvas, text=b2t, command=b2c, font=('Arial', 30), relief='flat').place(x=350,y=550) 

class entryfieldclass(standardclass): 
    def __init__(self, labeltext, b1t, b1c, b2t, b2c): 
        standardclass.__init__(self, labeltext, b1t, b1c, b2t, b2c) #calls the class's parent class's intialization subroutine
        self.usernamelabel = Label(self.canvas, text='Username: ', font=('Arial', 30), bg='#A9E2f3').place(x=100, y=250) 
        self.passwordlabel = Label(self.canvas, text='Password: ', font=('Arial', 30), bg='#A9E2f3').place(x=100, y=300) 
        self.usernameentryfield = Entry(self.canvas, font=('Arial', 30)).place(x=275,y=250, width=200) 
        self.passwordentryfield = Entry(self.canvas, font=('Arial', 30), show='*').place(x=275,y=300, width=200) 

def temporarysubroutine(): 
    print("The 'temporary subroutine' subroutine was run.") 

def revealregisterscreen(): 
    startscreen.canvas.pack_forget() 
    registerscreen = entryfieldclass('Register', 'Register', temporarysubroutine, 'Back', registerscreenback) 

def registerscreenback(): 
    registerscreen.canvas.pack_forget() 
    startscreen.canvas.pack() 

global startscreen
startscreen = entryfieldclass('Maths Revision Program', 'Login', temporarysubroutine, 'Register', revealregisterscreen)
```

[GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zMKp.png)

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYvfG.png)

Comment: ALL of your widget attributes are `None` - the result of calling `.pack()` or `.place()` on the widgets, NOT the widgets themselves.  You have to do the geometry management with a separate statement if you want to keep a reference to the widget.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tkinter: AttributeError: NoneType object has no attribute get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101750/tkinter-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-get)